# javascript for-loop not iterating within python loop

Tags: javascript, python, html, loops

I have a list of dates in python that I would like to iterate through to create button elements.

```
df2 = ['Sat Nov 12 11:57:21 CST 2022',
 'Wed Nov 23 18:13:31 CST 2022',
 'Wed Nov 23 18:13:32 CST 2022',
 'Thu Nov 10 19:07:50 CST 2022',
 'Fri Nov 11 09:54:54 CST 2022',
 'Fri Nov 11 10:18:36 CST 2022',
 'Sat Nov 26 10:50:05 CST 2022',
 'Sat Nov 12 11:57:50 CST 2022']
```

For some reason my javascript loop doesn't iterate the value yet outside the js loop it is iterating the value

```
for count, value in enumerate(df2):
    counts = str(count)
    f.write(''' 
            <html>
               <head> 
                  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
               </head> 
               <body> 
                  <div id="myHTMLWrapper"> 
                  '''+value+'''
                  </div>
                  <script>
              var wrapper = document.getElementById("myHTMLWrapper");
              var myHTML = '';
              for (var i = 0; i < '''+counts+'''; i++) {
                myHTML += '<button class="test">'''+value+'''</button>';
              }/*  w w  w  . j av a  2  s. c o  m*/
              wrapper.innerHTML = myHTML

                  </script>  
               </body>
            </html>
            ''')
```

So the value variable in my div there is iterating fine.  The buttons are also being generated but they have the **last** value of my list still...

Comment: How do you run this JavaScript?

Comment: If the problem is with the javascript, then show us the actual final javascript.

Comment: Why are you rendering anything with JavaScript if you're generating the HTML with Python, anyway? Also, should you really have an entire `<html>` for every member of `df2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're dfoing the looping in Python, as you are doing here, then you don't need to do any looping in Javascript.  The HTML you create will already have all of the data enumerated:

```
df2 = ['Sat Nov 12 11:57:21 CST 2022',
 'Wed Nov 23 18:13:31 CST 2022',
 'Wed Nov 23 18:13:32 CST 2022',
 'Thu Nov 10 19:07:50 CST 2022',
 'Fri Nov 11 09:54:54 CST 2022',
 'Fri Nov 11 10:18:36 CST 2022',
 'Sat Nov 26 10:50:05 CST 2022',
 'Sat Nov 12 11:57:50 CST 2022']



f.write(''' 
        <html>
           <head> 
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
           </head> 
           <body> 
''')

for count, value in enumerate(df2):
    f.write(''' 
              <div id="myHTMLWrapper"> '''+value+''' </div>
              '<button class="test">'''+value+'''</button>';
            ''')

f.write('''
   </body>
</html>
''')
```

Comment: You should give the div an unique ID, too. E.g. using `id="myHTMLWrapper'''count'''"`

Comment: This was great, just formatting wise I have the generated buttons stacked now instead of side by side which my js generated.

Comment: Then perhaps you want the `<div>`  to be outside of the loop and containing the buttons, instead of inside.

Comment: @Tim, so essentially var js_list = str(df2) to move my list to JS and perform the function within <script> ?

Comment: If you want to defer the real work to the Javascript, yes, that could be done.  I'd just as soon do it in the Python, but that's personal preference.